# Which is the priority: Performing Hajj or getting married?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, hajj

If someone has money and he is not married, and in the same time he wants to go to the Hajj, which one is preferred: performing Hajj or getting married?

Comment: I would guess, since it is an obligation on anyone who can afford it, that hajj would take precedent; marrying itself is not expensive, supporting a wife is, so you could put off the marriage by a few months.

Comment: @G.Bach Your guess is incorrect.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I saw, and upvoted; thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is the priority: Performing Hajj or getting married?

If someone has enough money to do both, then he should do both. In such a case, he may perform hajj, return to his homeland and get married or get married first and then perform hajj. But if he doesn't have enough money to do both or he fears that if he does one, he won't have enough money to do the other, then he should marry first. That is because the money he will spend to marry is approved by Sharia and isn't regarded as surplus wealth which he can use to perform hajj.

Allah says in the Quran (interpretation of the meaning):

> “And Hajj (pilgrimage to Makkah) to the House (Ka‘bah) is a duty that
>   mankind owes to Allaah, **those who can afford the expenses** (for one’s
>   conveyance, provision and residence)”
>
> [Aal ‘Imraan 3:97]

Reference: [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/41957)

Comment: Marriage is approved by Sharia, but lavishly spending on a marriage is questionable. There are many who take loans and spend lavishly on weddings beyond their means and this certainly would make the priority over Hajj questionable

Answer (score 0):

Hajj of course is preferred at the highest rank in heaven .

> ..."The best Jihad [for women] is Hajj-Mabrur"...
>
> <sub>[Sahih-al-Bukhari 2784](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/3)</sub>

And ranks of Jihadis are the highest 100 degrees at Heaven (Called Eden). Consider Marriage after Hajj

Comment: mmm, i really cant understand now, witch one i should to follow your answer or the answer of @Mohammad Sakib Arifin ?